# Reading integer from user input using scanner

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, integer, java.util.scanner

In the program i am creating i am creating a menu for the user made by using integer variables, when the user selects one they will activate that option in the menu. I am trying to use readnextInt but it is not working and i am not sure why. The code for the scanner is not working.

```
import java.util.Scanner;


 public class username
      {
    public static void main(String[] args)
{


    {   
       int Floor;
       Floor = 0;

       int Destination;
       Destination = 0;

       int UseLift;
       int AuditReport;
       int ExitLift;
       int a;


       UseLift = 1;
       AuditReport = 2;
       ExitLift = 3;
       a = read.NextInt;


       Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
       int a = in.nextInt();

       if (a == 1)
      System.out.println(" Enter your name ");

       else if (a == 2)
    System.out.println("");

       else if(a == 3)
    System.out.println(" Please Exit Lift ");

{
```

Comment: This doesn't even compile. Your `Scanner` instance is named `b` not `in`

Comment: Also what is this `a = read.NextInt;`??

Comment: In addition, the braces are not even correctly placed or matched.

Comment: @user3151959: Naming conventions are not compatible with JAVA standards.

Answer (score 1):

This line has your error.

```
Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = in.nextInt();
```

Your scanner is called b, not in. Use `b.nextInt()` instead.

```
Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = b.nextInt();
```

Also you have an errant Read.nextInt(), and you haven't defined Read. I don't think that line is trying to do anything, so just delete it.

Comment: I have done this now but it keeps asking me to rename a. there is still a red line under a in int a =b.nextInt();@Anubian Noob

Answer (score 0):

First, what is `read`? I don't see it defined as a `Scanner` anywhere.

Second, once `read` is defined (`Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);`), then you can call `nextInt()`, not `NextInt`. All methods need those parentheses when trying to call them.

Answer (score 0):

**Errors**:

The statement

```
a = read.NextInt;
```

seems redundant. variable `read` is undefined.

```
a = read.NextInt;

Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = in.nextInt();
```

Variable `in` is undefined but used to read `nextInt()`.

```
int a = in.nextInt();
```

It must be pointing to instance of `Scanner` class. Replace it with `b`.

You have defined `a` twice within the same scope. And hence your IDE must be showing a *red* line under

```
int a;
...
...
Scanner b = new Scanner(System.in);
int a = in.nextInt();
```

And, lastly, not an error but your code does not follow JAVA naming conventions for variable names and class names.
For more details Read [*Java Naming Conventions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java)

**Corrections suggested**:

1. Remove `a = read.nextInt;` as it seems redundant.
2. Remove `int a;` as you are redefining it after `Scanner`
   instantiation.
3. Change `int a = in.nextInt();` to `int a = b.nextInt();`

Answer (score 0):

Remaining code is correct just change this line  "int a = in.nextInt();" to "int a = b.nextInt();" as b is the name of your scanner and nextInt() is method belongs to Scanner class "in.nextInt()" is incorrect.